# How to merge data with Room Database in Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have two different class which one of these class includes list of other class.

There is a NewInvoice class below and it contains a list of invoice items.

```
@Entity(tableName = "invoices")
public class NewInvoice implements Parcelable {

@NonNull
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "transaction_id")
public int transaction_id;
@ColumnInfo(name = "invoiceNo")
public String invoiceNo;
@ColumnInfo(name = "contactId")
public String contactId;
@ColumnInfo(name = "currencyCode")
public String currencyCode;
@ColumnInfo(name = "description")
public String description;
@ColumnInfo(name = "creationDate")
public long creationDate;
@ColumnInfo(name = "invoiceDate")
public long invoiceDate;
@ColumnInfo(name = "dueDate")
public long dueDate;
@ColumnInfo(name = "shipmentDate")
public long shipmentDate;
@ColumnInfo(name = "invoiceDiscount")
public double invoiceDiscount;
@ColumnInfo(name = "discountType")
public byte discountType;
@ColumnInfo(name = "invoiceAmount")
public double invoiceAmount;
@ColumnInfo(name = "balance")
public double balance;
@ColumnInfo(name = "taxIncluded")
public boolean taxIncluded;
@ColumnInfo(name = "status")
public int status;
@ColumnInfo(name = "type")
public int type;

@Ignore
public List<InvoiceItem> invoiceItems;


public NewInvoice() {
}
```

Below is the InvoiceItem class

```
@Entity(tableName = "invoice_items")
public class InvoiceItem implements Parcelable {
@NonNull
@PrimaryKey()
@ColumnInfo(name = "itemId")
private String itemId;
@ColumnInfo(name = "invoiceId")
private String invoiceId;
@ColumnInfo(name = "unitPrice")
private double unitPrice;
@ColumnInfo(name = "quantity")
private double quantity;
@ColumnInfo(name = "inventoryId")
private String inventoryId;
@ColumnInfo(name = "taxIncluded")
private int taxIncluded;
@ColumnInfo(name = "taxRate")
private double taxRate;
@ColumnInfo(name = "discountRate")
private double discountRate;
@ColumnInfo(name = "discountType")
private int discountType;

public InvoiceItem() {
}
```

I am using Room database. Currently, I query NewInvoice records firstly and then InvoiceItem records related with NewInvoice record and adding InvoiceItem objects to the NewInvoice obcejt's invoiceItems array list.

Is there a way to query NewInvoice records that includes InvoiceItem records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, this would be achieved by having the two entities with `NewInvoice` (the list of invoiceItems isn't then needed but as it is ignored can be left) and then a third POJO class that embeds the `NewInvoice` with the `@Embedded` annotation and has the list of `InvoiceItem`s annotated with `@Relation`.

e.g.

```
class NewInvoiceWithListOfRelatedInvoiceItems {
    @Embedded
    private NewInvoice newInvoice;
    @Relation(
            entity = InvoiceItem.class,
            parentColumn = "invoiceNo",
            entityColumn = "invoiceId"
    )
    private List<InvoiceItem> invoiceItemList;

    public NewInvoice getNewInvoice() {
        return newInvoice;
    }

    public void setNewInvoice(NewInvoice newInvoice) {
        this.newInvoice = newInvoice;
    }

    public List<InvoiceItem> getInvoiceItemList() {
        return invoiceItemList;
    }

    public void setInvoiceItemList(List<InvoiceItem> invoiceItemList) {
        this.invoiceItemList = invoiceItemList;
    }
}
```

Then you can have an `@Query` such as (for a single NewInvoice)

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE invoiceNo=:invoiceNo")
NewInvoiceWithListOfRelatedInvoiceItems getInvoiceWithItems(String invoiceNo);
```

or for all NewInvoices then :-

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM invoices")
List<NewInvoiceWithListOfRelatedInvoiceItems> getAllInvoicesWithItems();
```

**Alternatively** you could, if you make the `@Dao` an abstract class, use just the classes you have (the POJO is then not required). By having the following Dao's e.g. :-

```
@Dao
abstract class NewInvoiceDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM invoice_items WHERE invoiceId=:invoiceNo")
    abstract List<InvoiceItem> getInvoiceItemsForANewInvoice(String invoiceNo);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE invoiceNo=:invoiceNo")
    abstract NewInvoice getNewInvoiceByInvoiceNo(String invoiceNo);

    @Transaction
    @Query("")
    NewInvoice getNewInvoiceWithInvoiceItems(String invoiceNo) {
        NewInvoice rv = getNewInvoiceByInvoiceNo(invoiceNo);
        rv.setInvoiceItems(getInvoiceItemsForANewInvoice(invoiceNo));
        return rv;
    }
}
```

**Additional**

In either case it would be advisable to have an index on the `invoiceNo` and the `invoiceId` columns (assuming that this is the column used for the relationship).

So for **NewInvoice** you could have the `@Entity` annotation as :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "invoices", indices = {@Index(value = "invoiceNo", unique = true)})
```

And for **InvoiceItem** have the `@ColumnInfo` for the **invoiceId** column as :-

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "invoiceId", index = true)
private String invoiceId;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get NewInvoice records that include InvoiceItem records, you need this query:

```
SELECT invoiceNo
  FROM invoices
 WHERE invoiceNo IN (
           SELECT invoiceId
             FROM invoice_items
       );
```

If 'invoiceNo' in 'invoices' equals 'invoiceId' in 'invoice_items'.

In case you are new to subqueries: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-subquery/

Comment: Thank you for response but I needed to query with room. I found the solution in the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships